# React Query - useIsFetching

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I'm having a problem with the useIsFetching hook when using a single queryKey.
I am using tanstacks react-query v5 and building a useQuery function like this.

```
useQuery<SomeType[]>({
        queryKey: ["key1", "key2"],
        queryFn: async () => {
            ...
        },
    });
```

Now I want to use the `useIsFetching` hook with only the second query key ("key2").

```
const isFetching = useIsFetching({ queryKey: ["key2"] });
```

but this does not work.
If I take only the first Key ["key1"], it works perfectly.
If I take both keys in sequence ["key1", "key2"], it also works perfectly.

At the end I want to trigger isFetching with "key2" to start a loading spinner while this key is fetching.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a predicate function in `useIsFetching` for this.

```
const isFetching = useIsFetching({
    predicate: query => query.queryKey.at(1) === 'key2',
});
```

It will match all the queries with 'key2' in the 2nd index of the queryKey. You can customize it based on your requirements.

More: https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/reference/useIsFetching

Filter: https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/guides/filters#query-filters